# Sharepoint Online to AS/400 DB2

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a requirement to connect from Sharepoint online to AS/400 DB2 server. I need to read and write as well.

Is there any way to connect like BCS etc?

If you have the steps please share.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done an AS/400 DB2 integration but many other integrations.

I would suggest to write your own interface. E.g a WebService interface or a FileExchange interface. With this layer in mind you have control over all the data that should be transferred to SharePoint and vice versa.

You should ask yourself if you want to to duplicate the data from AS/400 to SharePoint via BCS? I guess this is not what you want to have.

From my point of view writing your own DataExchange Layer is the way to do it.